# Problem with getting data from database, "render" function error

Tags: node.js, postgresql, express

I am quite new to express and I created a database in Postgres to extract the data about blog posts to place the information in an ejs file.
I get the error:

```
 Cannot read property 'send' of undefined
```

I've tried to call `db.getPosts()` with `res` and `req`, but it's not possible to set a header again, returns an error.

The problematic chunk of code in my `query.js` file:

```
const getPosts = (_req, res) => {
    pool.query('SELECT * FROM blog_posts', (error, results) => {
        console.log(error);
        // console.log(results.rows);
        if (error) {
            throw error
        }
        return res.send(results.rows );
    })
}
```

`send(results.rows)` or `render('blog', {posts: results.rows})` called on `res` give the exact same error.

Function in `server.js` that is supposed to use this data is as follows:

```
app.get("/blog", function (req, res) {
    const posts = db.getPosts();
    res.render("blog", { posts: posts });
});
```

What do I do wrong? I lack some knowledge, that is for sure, so please, if you can help, explain this briefly to me if possible.

Also, is `send()` function a correct function to get the data to operate on in `server.js`? Many tutorials suggest `json()` but then I don't really get the proper data format, it is just displayed in the browser.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make `getPosts` receive a callback:

```
const getPosts = (callback) => {
    pool.query('SELECT * FROM blog_posts', (error, results) => {
        console.log(error);
        // console.log(results.rows);
        if (error) {
            throw error
        }
        callback(results.rows);
    })
}
```

Usage would be something like:

```
app.get("/blog", function (req, res) {
    db.getPosts(function(rows) {
        res.render("blog", {posts: rows})
    });
});
```

Answer (score -1):

in your getPosts method do not use send. just return results.rows. upate your code like below.

```
const getPosts = () => {
    pool.query('SELECT * FROM blog_posts', (error, results) => {
        console.log(error);
        // console.log(results.rows);
        if (error) {
            throw error
        }
        return results.rows;
    })
}
```

also you need to use async await while calling getposts as it is a async function. update the code like below.

```
app.get("/blog", async function (req, res) {
    const posts = await db.getPosts();
    res.render("blog", { posts: posts });
});
```

Comment: await wont't be working in this case ,as neither the function is returning promise and neither the callback is async

Comment: `posts` in your route will be `undefined`

Comment: Yes, they are undefined, do you know why?

Comment: @MartaP that's unrelated to this question and answer's here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call